# Modify the CSV file to add addtional comma using script task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, ssis

I have a CSV file in the following format

> "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "300","331"
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "700","701

In the above data, I want to add additional comma's after the numeric values in the 4th and the last row after the file is read using the `Flat File Source`, in this case 6 additional comma's should be added in the 4th and the last row
so the correct data would be like this

> "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "300","331",,,,,,
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext","Sometext",
>     "700","701,,,,,,

I have to add the comma's in the dataset only without modifying the existing file
How can this be achieved in SSIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go would be to use a **Script Component** set as your source in your Data Flow Task. Find a detailed example in the following article on what it should include:

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/106/posts/11128/ssis-script-component-add-missing-column-or-ignore-extra-columns.aspx

This would add missing columns, as well as ignore any extra ones depending on your first header row.